# android location.distanceBetween and Using previous location

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to calculate the length of a polyline by adding up the distances between points as I am moving.

I'm wanting to use this method:

```
 distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```

I can place location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude() in the endLat & endLong.

I'm placing all of this inside the onLocationChanged(Location location) { }

How can I save the location from the last time onLocationChanged(Location location) was called and use it as the startLatitude/Longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `global temp variable` to save the previous Location update. If you need more than one Location you can also use a List.

```
private Locaction previous;

@Override
public void onLocationChange(Location location) {
    ...
    // if its the first location update temp is null!
    if (previous != null) {
         Location.distanceBetween(
                  previous.getLatitude(),
                  previous.getLongitude(),
                  location.getLatitude(),
                  location.getLongitude(),
                  results);
    }

    // hold the location
    previous = location;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works good. How would I sum the total distance between all points? I've changed my method to distancesph = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(previous, current); so that it returns a double each time. How would I add the double up each time to get a total distance as I travel?

Comment: With the same approach. Sum the distance to a global variable every time you have done a calculation. Something like this `distancesph += SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(previous, current)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Maps Directions API. You'll need to request the directions over HTTP. You can do this directly from Android, or via your own server.

For example, directions from Montreal to Toronto:

GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false
You'll end up with some JSON. In routes[].legs[].distance, you'll get an object like this:

```
 "legs" : [
    {
       "distance" : {
          "text" : "542 km",
          "value" : 542389
       },
```